# How to get text from table cell

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to get the text `2010 manstreet san Jose ca` from the HTML below. I have tried using XPath `contains`. It doesn't work.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HTML:

```
<input id="St" type="hidden" value="1" name="St"/>
<div>
<div style="text-align:right;width:428px;">
<style> .myStyle { border: 1px solid silver;  background-color: #F9E0E0; } </style>
<input id="hd" type="hidden" value="" name="hD"/>

<input id="Deleting" type="hidden" value="" name="D"/>
<h3>somthing</h3>
<br/>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
2010 manstreet 
<br/>
san jose CA 95124
</td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: Show the xpath code. We fix what you've written, we don't write it for you.

Comment: Hello  @MarcB , this is how I tried                                           //tr/td[contains(text(), '2010 manstreet')]

Comment: given that your html above has `manstreet`, and not `main street`, of course it's not going to match anything. `contains` is an exact substring match. it's not a "close enough" match.

Comment: I have wrongly spelled it here but I have tried it with exact text matching. still, it was not able to find it.

Comment: Are the elements inside some iframe tag or frame tag that it is not written in your HTML code? Because you need a different approach in this case

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `.` instead of `text()` in your `xpath` as below :-

```
//tr/td[contains(., '2010 manstreet')]
```

Hope it works...:)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm now able to get the text.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good approach to find element by refferring the text you want to get since it could be change for another case. Instead you can get the element by `"table > tbody"`, check the following python console:

```
>>> print driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table > tbody").text
2010 manstreet
san jose CA 95124
```